# ANCOVA with repeated measures IV, violation of slopes

Tags: ancova, assumptions

I am running a 2x2x5 mixed factorial ANCOVA, with one within-groups variable, and two between groups variable. I want to check for violation of homogeneity of regression slopes.  My covatiate does not interact with my between groups variables.  It does however interact with my within-groups variable.  Is this still a violation of the assumption?